# Linking to external fonts which have the same name?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm using fonts from a font repository which often stores different fonts under the same name. For example, two different fonts might be:

```
<link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/edeb336ecd776e23d99355eb2b52cbc7?family=NeuzeitGroteskW01-Regular" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/[some other random character string]?family=NeuzeitGroteskW01-Regular" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Including both of the above links in my page's `<head>` means that the second version of the font will be the one that's referenced as `NeuzeitGroteskW01-Regular` in the CSS. Is there a way to use, from an external server, multiple fonts which share the same name?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "clean" way of doing so because overwriting CSS rules is pretty much part of its functionality.

Maybe you could load the CSS with javascript using a XHR, replace the name of the font in the XHR response and add the new string as a CSS rule with **insertRule** on the fly.

Again, it is not clean, but should do the trick.
Here is some information about **insertRule**.

[CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)

Comment: Indeed - doesn't seem like the cleanest approach, but an interesting idea. Thanks!